# django support on aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I'm building a web app with Django 1.6 and was looking to use AWS with it. I saw AWS has been tested with Django 1.4.1 and 1.3.3 but couldn't find if AWS supported Django 1.6.

If anyone has any experience with AWS for Django and could tell me if it would be safe to use Django 1.6 with AWS that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

AWS - specifically, Amazon EC2 - does not care what version of Django you run on it. It's infrastructure-as-a-service, not platform-as-a-service like Heroku or Gondor, so it's up to you to install and configure your hosting environment. So you can use whatever version you want of software at any level of the stack, from the OS up to Django.

If you're not sure what you're doing, though, one of those PaaS companies would probably be better for you.

Comment: I see a lot of people going with aws, but I am a little worried about all the config. How would you compare google app engine against aws? Would it be better to learn all about databases and go with aws or let Google handle everything?

Comment: The question is not databases, but server config generally. And I wouldn't really recommend Google for this (I presume you mean GAE), but Heroku (which is actually built on AWS) or Gondor (built on Rackspace).

Comment: I meant server config, but only realized I put databases after I posted the comment. Is Heroku just as scalable as AWS? I'm assuming so if its built on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put - AWS has linux servers in the cloud (EC2) - IaaS - that can be used just as you would use a physical, standalone linux installation. So feel free to install whatever version of Django you like, as long as that linux flavor supports that version, AWS EC2 will support it too. :-)

By the way, you can opt for AWS's free tier that gives you access to almost all AWS services for free (for a year!) and you can try and see for yourself if that would work for you.